# Ubuntu 15.10 doesn't shutdown after installing Cinnamon

Tags: shutdown

I changed my Ubuntu interface from the classic Unity to Cinnamon and after that shutdown doesn't work properly. I first have to log out and then shutdown else it wont make so. From terminal shutdown works fine. Do you have any solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you click super (Or windows icon on keyboard) search for power managment. New windows will pop up. Click *when power button is pressed* click shutdown immediately. I had a similar problem and this was a workaround.